# input date validation check calling to_date

Tags: postgresql, date

I'm using postgreSQL-9.1.6 on CENTOS.

I have issue on **to_date** function like...

```
postgres=# select to_date('20130229','yyyymmdd');
  to_date   
------------
 2013-03-01
(1 row)
```

so I'm trying to add validation check for out of range against incoming date.

> postgres=# select to_date('20130229','yyyymmdd');
>
> ERROR:  timestamp out of range

I found a hint from [here](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commitdiff;h=d4c78c1811d14b14f47f3611bf2c2c1a35817988) but it didn't work and I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17519851/raise-error-when-date-is-not-valid).
unfortunately, I couldn't get answer.

Finally, I reached another conclustion. Below is My **formatting.c** to which 9 lines marked `+` added.

```
Datum
to_date(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
        text       *date_txt = PG_GETARG_TEXT_P(0);
        text       *fmt = PG_GETARG_TEXT_P(1);
        DateADT         result;
        struct pg_tm tm;
        fsec_t          fsec;

    +   int ndays[]={-1,31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31};

    +   int last_day_of_month;

        do_to_timestamp(date_txt, fmt, &tm, &fsec);

    +   last_day_of_month = ndays[tm.tm_mon];
    +   if (((tm.tm_year & 3) == 0 && ((tm.tm_year % 25) != 0 || (tm.tm_year & 15) == 0)) && tm.tm_mon == 2 )
    +           last_day_of_month = ndays[tm.tm_mon] + 1;

    +   if( tm.tm_mon > 12 || tm.tm_mon < 1 || tm.tm_mday > last_day_of_month || tm.tm_mday < 1
)
    +           ereport(ERROR,
    +                           (errcode(ERRCODE_DATETIME_VALUE_OUT_OF_RANGE),
    +                            errmsg("timestamp out of range")));

        result = date2j(tm.tm_year, tm.tm_mon, tm.tm_mday) - POSTGRES_EPOCH_JDATE;

        PG_RETURN_DATEADT(result);
}
```

although my own **formatting.c** works well, I'm not sure this works perfect. I'm worried about unexpected results like throwing error against the valid date.

Any advice would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Must you do this by patching your server code? Especially when that patch will probably break currently working SQL and will need to be updated when you update PostgreSQL? This is also a bad idea because you'll get in the habit of expecting `to_date` to work the way your custom `to_date` works and things will go sideways when you work with an unpatched PostgreSQL. You might want to take into account other people that get stuck working with your custom PostgreSQL server too, how are they supposed to know that `to_date` really isn't `to_date` but some modified version? OTOH, perhaps you're doing this for job security.

Why not write your own `to_date` replacement function, called say `strict_to_date`, that does the conversion using `to_date` and then does a simple:

```
string = to_char(to_date_result, 'yyyymmdd')
```

comparison? If the `to_date` and `to_char` round trip doesn't give you your original result back then you can raise your exception. You'd need to decide what `strict_to_date(null)` would do of course but that's easy to add.

Consider some simple results:

```
=> select to_date('20130229','yyyymmdd');
  to_date   
------------
 2013-03-01
(1 row)

=> select to_char(to_date('20130229','yyyymmdd'), 'yyyymmdd');
 to_char  
----------
 20130301
(1 row)
```

Since `'20130229' != '20130301'` you have your exception. Wrap that in a function and slip in a little comment about why you're doing this and everyone should be happy.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. create strict_to_date would be better though,another point is my date validation check. My formatting.c MUST NOT throw exception against valid date.

Comment: What part of your date validation wouldn't be covered by a `to_date`-`to_char` round trip? I don't think the string check would reject any valid dates.